# How to run an up-to-date Thunderbird package with HDPI+Wayland support on 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, thunderbird, wayland

To use Thunderbird on Ubuntu 22.04 I have these options:

- Install from Ubuntu deb repos. (I've done this forever.)

  - ✔ correctly rendered on hdpi and legacy screens
  - ✖ about 10 versions behind!
  - ✔ quick to load
  - ~ all my accounts, plugins, config present.
- Install from Ubuntu snap repos.

  - ✖ blurry on hdpi
  - ✔ up-to-date version (102)
  - ✖ takes ages to load
  - ✖ can't seem to import my existing profiles + config (several GB of data)
- Install from 3rd party AppImage

  - ✖ blurry on hdpi
  - ✔ up-to-date packages available.
  - ✔ loads fast
  - ✔ finds my config at `~/.thunderbird`
- Install from Mozilla ppa for Ubuntu 22.04

  - ✔ correctly rendered on hdpi and legacy screens
  - ✖ still 10 versions behind - only minor versions ahead of main repos.
  - ✔ quick to load
  - ✔ all my accounts, plugins, config present.

Comment: Here is a recent solution: [Can I install Thunderbird 115 as a .deb package?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1480467/229365).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how:

1. Visit https://www.thunderbird.net/ and download the latest thunderbird. You're hoping for a .tar.bz file.
2. un-tar that file.
3. Launch thunderbird from within the extracted thunderbird/ directory using:

   ```
   export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1
   ./thunderbird
   ```

Hey presto! Works with fractional scaling HDPI and legacy screens and starts fast too.